# Mongo Connection String

Tags: digital-ocean, ubuntu-server, droplet

I'm currently trying to connect my nodejs app to mongodb on the same droplet.

I currently have `auth = true` and droplet ip to the bind address and allowed my public ip to the ufw port connections.

This does allow me to remote in to my droplet from mongo compass.

The issue I'm having is this:

Let's say this is my connection string: `mongodb://user:pass@droplet-ip:27017/DB-NAME`

That connection string works fine on remote.

When I add my connection string to my nodejs app, something like this: `mongodb://user:pass@127.0.0.1:27017/DB-NAME` ***it doesn't connect.***

But when I do `mongodb://user:pass@127.0.0.1:27017/` ***without specifying the DB-NAME it does connect***.

I did create an admin account using the following methods:

1. `use admin`
2. `db.createUser({user: "user", pwd: "password", roles: ["root"]});`

If I `use admin` and do a `db.getUsers();` I get :

```
 users: 
   [ { _id: 'admin.user',
       user: 'user',
       db: 'admin',
       roles: 
        [ { role: 'userAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' },
          { role: 'readWriteAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' } ] } ],
  ok: 1
```

Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well it just took a little more testing. Ended up being that I was suppose to include `?authSource=admin` to the end of the connection string.